# Employer reduced working hours to 25%

Tags: employment, germany

I am employed in a startup that financially struggles and has decided to merge with another startup. As a result I have been informed that my working hours (as well as salary) will be reduced ***to 25%*** (10 working hours per week).

My contract lists two paragraphs. First one saying that my working hours are flexibel based on operational requirements. Second one saying that my salary depends on my working hours.

So far I have worked for 40 hours per week.

I found several articles online claiming that a reduction is only valid ***by 20-25%***, so approximately 30 working hours per week (eg. [here](https://www.ra-poeppel.de/gehalt-arbeitszeit-nicht-einseitig-gekuerzt/), [here](https://www.wirtschaftsforum.de/tipps/arbeitszeitverkuerzung-das-darf-der-arbeitgeber) and [here](https://www.helpster.de/stundenkuerzung-durch-arbeitgeber-rechtliche-hinweise_219017)).

Now my questions are:

- What law is a reduction to only 20-25% based on?
- Do I have to be informed by my employer in a written form?

Comment: I think you need a lawyer who can look at the entire contract. This is way too serious for generic advice on a website.

Comment: But the two questions above are concrete and reasonable anyway, no?

Comment: Not without reading the contract, but you should **not** post that here even with PII redacted.

Comment: German law differentiates between Teilzeit and Kurzarbeit *Ist für die Dauer der wöchentlichen Arbeitszeit nach Absatz 1 Satz 2 eine Höchstarbeitszeit vereinbart, darf der Arbeitgeber nur bis zu 20 Prozent der wöchentlichen Arbeitszeit weniger abrufen* https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/tzbfg/__12.html